# drawing on top of the image using paperjs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, paperjs

I'm using Paper.js to draw lines on canvas. 
I want to be able to upload local image to the paperjs canvas and then be able to draw on top of it.

What I did is:

```
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    function make_base()
    {
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = "http://paperjs.org/tutorials/images/working-with-rasters/mona.jpg";
      context.drawImage(img, 100, 100);
    }
    document.getElementById('imageUpload').addEventListener('click', function(){
      make_base();
    });
```

This successfully adds an image to my canvas, but when I draw on canvas, image disappears and the image is on top of the lines, should be behind them.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the image to the paper project as a paperjs Raster item, as such

```
var raster = new Raster({
    source: "http://paperjs.org/tutorials/images/working-with-rasters/mona.jpg",
    position: view.center
});
```

It will be inserted into the project in the current layer. You can then use paperjs functions like sendToBack and bringToFront to manipulate what appears where. I would probably put the raster image on the first Layer then add a new Layer for the drawing to make it easy to keep track of.

Comment: im trying to create a raster as given above but for some reason I see only half of the image.

Comment: no code - nothing to look at. consider asking a question. consider voting for my answers. you've got 5400 rep, I'd think you'd be aware that asking questions in comments isn't generally the right way to approach things.

Comment: sorry, I did not get much response on my paperjs questions, so thought will get your attention..I just posted this separately - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51072412/paperjs-select-items-and-delete-on-mouse-click

Comment: Understood but you didn't even vote for my answer in the previous question that you copied, had a problem with, and I solved for you. I don't want to be transactional - I created that script to help people but when it's clearly of value to someone it would be nice if they indicated so.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to change or working with the image, use background-image on canvas tag:

```
<canvas id="canvas" 
        style="background-image: url(http://paperjs.org/tutorials/images/working-with-rasters/mona.jpg);"></canvas>
```